# Regex Erasing all except numbers with limited digits

Tags: regex

What I want to do is erase everything except `\d{4,7}` *only by replacing*.
Any ideas to get this?

ex)
`G-A15239L → 15239`
(**G-A** and **L** should be selected and replaced by empty strings)
`now200316stillcovid19asdf → 200316`
(**now** and **stillcovid19asdf** should be selected and replaced by empty strings)

Also, replacing text is not limited as empty string.
substitutions such as $1 are possible too.

Using Regex in 'Kustom' apps. (including KLCK, KLWP, KWGT)
I don't know which engine it's using because there are no information about it

Comment: Try `(\d{4,7})?.?` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Could you please clarify: does `^.*?(\d{4,7}).*` work for you, too?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `^.*?(\d{4,7}).*` worked only at one line text, not for multilines.
`(\d{4,7})?.?` worked at both

Comment: Ok, I posted the answer with two variations of the pattern + mentioning that there should be an additional pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\d{4,7})?.?
```

Or

```
(\d{4,7})|.
```

and replace with `$1`.  See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJMTYH/2).

**Details**

- `(\d{4,7})?` - an optional (due to `?` at the end - if it is missing, then the group is obligatory) capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of 4 to 7 digits
- `|` - or
- `.?` - any one char other than line break chars, 1 or 0 times when `?` is right after it.

So, any match of 4 to 7 digits is kept (since `$1` refers to the Group 1 value) and if there is a char after it, it is removed.

It looks as if the regex is Java based since all non-matching groups are replaced with `null`:

[image]

So, the only possible solution is to use a second pass to post-process the results, just replace `null` with some kind of a delimiter, a newline for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Search:   .*?(\d{4,7})[^\d]+|.*
Replace:  $1
```

in for instance Notepad++ 6.0 or better (which comes with built-in [PCRE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) support) works with your examples:

```
jalsdkfilwsehf
now200316stillcovid19asdf
G-A15239L
```

becomes:

```
200316
15239
```